# Simple example using regex doesn't work

Tags: regex, bash

I try to use regexes in my bash script. I don't understand why the result of this simple example is "ko":

```
foo='bar'; if [[ $foo =~ '^[a-z]+$' ]] ; then echo "ok"; else echo "ko"; fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove both `'`:

```
foo='bar'; if [[ $foo =~ ^[a-z]+$ ]] ; then echo "ok"; else echo "ko"; fi
```